# window.status in blazor after completely render

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I want to write
'window.status= "completed"'
when Blazor page completely load in code behind.

I have small knowledge of JS.

Comment: Read the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-javascript-isolation-and-object-references

Answer (score 1):

`window.status` has no browser support anymore and is deprecated so should not be used.

Read the deprecation details in below links:

1. https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/7383
2. https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_window_status
3. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blazor gives you great opportunities to interact with DOM, and in most scenarios, javascript is not a necessity anymore. Unfortunately, as in your case, we can't "reach" the window. It is too high in the hierarchy. And we need to use Javascript interop.

The first step is to create a javascript file and include it as a link in the index.html if you are using WASM or Host.cshtml for server-side Blazor. Alternatively, you can embed it in the document.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
myAppNamespace.setCompleteStatus= function (status) {
  document.status = status;
};
</script>
```

It is a good practice to keep your scripts in their own namespace. That is the `myAppNamespace` in the example before. Blazor will need this information to call the right function later.

In your component that should trigger this operation, inject the javascript Interop service.

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsruntime
```

Each Blazor component has a life cycle with different methods being executed based on its state. The method `OnAfterRenderAsync` is executed after all the rendering is done. You can override it and execute your javascript.

```
    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

        if(firstRender == true)
        {
            await jsruntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myAppNamespace.setCompleteStatus", "insert status here");
        }
    }
```

As the name suggested `firstRender` is only set to true once the component is added to the DOM. If you need to change the status multiple times, you can drop the condition. Keep in mind to change `myAppNamespace` in this method call as well.